# Can I make puff pastry with half the butter?

Tags: butter, puff-pastry

I made puff pastry with Gouda cheese inside and it turned out really good. The only problem I had was the amount of butter and it was too buttery. I'd like to know if it is possible to reduce the amount of butter? Another question is, I have some leftover dough without butter (a combination of flour, salt and ice water) and I was wondering for 420 gr dough how much butter should I use?

Comment: If you're trying to repair a recipe, it's generally helpful to post the original recipe. Also if you can, keep your questions concise: you've asked three questions about puff pastry dough in a relatively short time period, and I have the feeling people are going to end up writing some of the same things to answer all of them.

Answer (score 3):

The secret lies in the folding of the dough...You may uses half the butter but you would ultimately have to fold it more before cooking it. The more you fold the dough the more puffy it gets, of course your results will get better with more butter, but in that particular situation, go with the extra folding, you'll get a decent pastry this way.

Answer (score -2):

Normally people use about the same amount of flour and butter, but you can without problem have the half amount in butter, but the puff pastry will be more dry.

This would lead to a recipe of approximately:

200g flour

100g butter at room temp

100g cold water

some salt

Comment: Room temperature butter does not puff pastry make...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think the key to puff pastry is very cold butter, very cold flour, ice cold water, even cold blender! And the amounts you mentioned wouldn't work, 100 g water?

Comment: There are tons of puff pastry recipes with not cold butter and water. But @Gigili, why dont you share your recipe now you was the original asker, and already are dizzing mine?

Comment: I did actually post it in almost all of my questions about puff pastry.

Comment: Interesting to read the different views on butter temperature when making butter puff dough. In my experience, the most important thing to remember is to 'match' the dough consistency with the type of butter you are going to use. In other words, if you are using room temperature butter, you make a softer dough. If you are using cold butter, you make a stiffer dough. It's all about making sure you can keep your layers stratified without working the fat into the dough. If you had a soft dough and hard butter, the dough would be torn all to hell...